# How do i get the value of a radiobutton and insert it into mysql database with java eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql

i have created 2 radiobuttons (male and female) and grouped them together.

```
private JTextField textFieldFName;
private JTextField textFieldLName;
private JTextField textFieldUserName;
private JTextField textFieldDOB;
private JTextField textFieldNRIC;
private JTextField textFieldEmail;
private JTextField textFieldAdd;
private JTextField textFieldPhoneNo;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JRadioButton rdbtnMale;
private JRadioButton rdbtnFemale;
private ButtonGroup group;
```

...

```
    JRadioButton rdbtnMale = new JRadioButton("Male", true);
    rdbtnMale.setBounds(278, 357, 109, 23);
    setLayer(rdbtnMale,3);
    add(rdbtnMale);

    JRadioButton rdbtnFemale = new JRadioButton("Female", false);
    rdbtnFemale.setBounds(400, 357, 109, 23);
    setLayer(rdbtnFemale,3);
    add(rdbtnFemale);

    group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(rdbtnMale);
    group.add(rdbtnFemale);
```

normally if i used a textField, i would do this

```
    private boolean createUserOk(JFrame mf) {
    boolean success = false;
    // retrieve the user input from the text box/area provided
    if (validateInput(mf)) {
        // create an object of expenses based on the input values
        Customer e1 = new Customer(textFieldFName.getText(),
                textFieldLName.getText(), textFieldUserName.getText(),
                passwordField.getText(), textFieldGender.getText(),
                textFieldDOB.getText(), textFieldNRIC.getText(),
                textFieldEmail.getText(), textFieldAdd.getText(),
                textFieldPhoneNo.getText());
        // insert to database and check return value

        if (cc.createCustomer(e1)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mf, "User created successfully",
                    "Alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            // reset text field for next record.
            textFieldFName.setText("");
            textFieldLName.setText("");
            textFieldUserName.setText("");
            passwordField.setText("");
            textFieldGender.setText("");
            textFieldDOB.setText("");
            textFieldNRIC.setText("");
            textFieldEmail.setText("");
            textFieldAdd.setText("");
            textFieldPhoneNo.setText("");
            success = true;

        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mf,
                    "Database Error. Record not created.", "Alert",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return success;
}
```

However, since im using RadioButtons for gender instead of a `textFieldGender`, how should i do to get the values of what was checked? instead of using `getText` for a textField?

Comment: `JRadioButton#isSelected`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group.getSelection().getActionCommand()` to know which gender is selected and set your gender for `Customer`

```
JRadioButton rdbtnMale = new JRadioButton("Male");
rdbtnMale.setActionCommand("male");
JRadioButton rdbtnFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
rdbtnFemale.setActionCommand("female");

ButtonGroup group= new ButtonGroup();
group.add(rdbtnMale);
group.add(rdbtnFemale);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        System.out.println("Selected Radio Button: " + group.getSelection().getActionCommand());
}
```

Comment: @Jere .. actionPerformed in not static so it can't be? Can you show me how you get it into your code?

Comment: thanks! it works fine now but im getting a nullPointerException from  group.getSelection().getActionCommand()

Comment: did you added .setActionCommand("female"); and .setActionCommand("male"); ? @Jere

Comment: yes i did! JRadioButton rdbtnMale = new JRadioButton("Male");
  rdbtnMale.setBounds(278, 357, 109, 23);
  setLayer(rdbtnMale,3);
  add(rdbtnMale);
  rdbtnMale.setActionCommand("Male");
  
  JRadioButton rdbtnFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
  rdbtnFemale.setBounds(400, 357, 109, 23);
  setLayer(rdbtnFemale,3);
  add(rdbtnFemale);
  rdbtnFemale.setActionCommand("Female");

  ButtonGroup group= new ButtonGroup();
  group.add(rdbtnMale);
  group.add(rdbtnFemale);

Comment: @Jere can you add the stacktrace and the statement which is pointed by line number in stacktrace for null pointer

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ui.Customer.CustomerRegistration.createUserOk(CustomerRegistration.java:276)
 at ui.Customer.CustomerRegistration.access$1(CustomerRegistration.java:269)
 at ui.Customer.CustomerRegistration$1.actionPerformed(CustomerRegistration.java:175)

Comment: 276: passwordField.getText(),group.getSelection().getActionCommand(),

Comment: 269: private boolean createUserOk(JFrame mf) {
boolean success = false
  if (validateInput(mf)) {
  
Customer e1 = new Customer(textFieldFName.getText(),

     textFieldLName.getText(), 
                                  textFieldUserName.getText(),                         passwordField.getText(),
group.getSelection().getActionCommand(),textFieldDOB.getText(), textField

Comment: 175:   if (createUserOk(mf) == true) {

     CustomerLogin contentPane = new 

CustomerLogin(mf);
     mf.setContentPane(contentPane);
     mf.setVisible(true);

Comment: @Jere 276 is too long statement, cant say which one is throwing null. you need to sop each of them and figure out which is null.

Answer (score 0):

the following code snippet may help you.

it will give you the text of selected radio button. you may use this approach.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class GroupButtonUtils {
public String getSelectedButtonText(ButtonGroup buttonGroup) {
    for (Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = buttonGroup.getElements(); buttons.hasMoreElements();) {
        AbstractButton button = buttons.nextElement();

        if (button.isSelected()) {
            return button.getText();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's small and short way to get selected radio button value. (Only two radio buttons)

```
JRadioButton rdbtnMale = new JRadioButton("Male");
JRadioButton rdbtnFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");

ButtonGroup group= new ButtonGroup();
group.add(rdbtnMale);
group.add(rdbtnFemale);

public void getSelectedValue() OR public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ee)
{    
       if(rdbtnMale.isSelected())
        {
            return (rdbtnMale.getText()); //Male
        }
        else
        {
            return(rdbtnFemale.getText()); //Female
        }
}
```